# Jquery Mobile display Label above a Listview

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to display a label `<label> My Listview </label>` just above a listview on the content div.
however the listview is not displayed properly, it goes above half of the label

```
<div data-role="content">
   <label>My Listview</label>
   <ul data-role="listview">
     <li>Item 1</li>
     <li>Item 2</li>
     <li>Item 3</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Layout is not properly displayed, i'm using version 1.4.5, how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The not inset listview has a negative 1em margin. This allows it to reach the page edges by defeating any content padding. In your case, you just need to set the top margin to 0 (and possibly bottom margin too if you have controls below it):

```
.ui-content .ui-listview {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

You can also set `data-inset="true"` on the `<ul>` if you want that look.

Answer (score 2):

Add css for margin to bottom:

```
.ui-mobile label {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 0 1em 0; // you can change as you wish.
 }
```